# How to end the process

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I created a windows application using .net. It works fine. My doubt is application is running in background even though i close the application.once closed the application also in task manager application still running .How to end the process. Give me your suggestion.

Comment: Can you show how you write & launch the code ?

Comment: In task manager does it consume cpu or just memory ? In addition, download Process Explorer its much better then task manager ..  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: You can call Application.Exit() when you want to close down your application.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have some called "Thread" in your application

Check if the threads stopped when application close, if not, stop them on "Form close" event

Post some of your code if possible

Answer (score 0):

I guess you created a thread and launched the Process from that thread.
By default, a thread would be a Foreground thread. So, even if you close the MainWindow, the application
would continue to run.
On your main form close, do these
1) // Close process by sending a close message to its main window.
            myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
            // Free resources associated with process.
            myProcess.Close();
     Both the calls are required!!
2) Stop the thread

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sharma,
Problem resolved once i add the Application.Exit()in the close button.